# need a macro that can reorder sheets in an excel spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

i have several workbooks that have sheets that are not in order (like sheet A,C,B)

i need a macro that can reorder the sheets so that they are in order (like sheet A,B,C).

can anyone assist me?

Comment: Please show what you have already tried, as this site is for providing assistance and not custom scripts.

Comment: im not sure where to start with this project. i know how to create the sheets but the code that im using doesnt know how to reorder the tabs. basically im creating the sheet after the "last" tab, but that is fixed. so when i create my sheets, the order is backwards. any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not only is Junno correct, you will also need to explain yourself better about what you mean when you say "*sheets that are not in order*". Do you mean the data in columns labeled "A, C, B", or these are the actual names on the tabs of the sheets. It may be helpful for you to offer a screen shot. Please have a look at ***[ask]*** to learn how to improve your question.

Comment: You could use the macro record facility to manually do what you wanted to do, and view the output to at least put you on the right track.

Comment: no im not talking about columns. these are the names of the sheets themselves. so i have a routine that creates pages (named A,B,C) but when i run the routine, the pages come out as C,B,A so i need to reorder them so that they come out as A,B,C. the pages go up to ZZZZZ, so after Z, then it goes AA,BB, etc. since i am new to VBA, im not sure where to start with this. appreciate any help.

Comment: As @Jonno said, record yourself doing it and then figure out the code.

Comment: so here is the code from the recorder, but i still dont know how to program this unless i create all the pages and then record the reorder, but this will only work if i have all the pages to work with, if i only have C,B,A then the routine will fail as there are the other pages that need to be worked with. here is the code. 'code'     Sheets("A").Select
    Sheets("A").Move Before:=Sheets(5)
    Sheets("B").Select
    Sheets("B").Move Before:=Sheets(6)

Comment: so here is the code from the recorder. what i need is an if then statement to see if the page exists, then i can do the move.    Sheets("C").Select
    Sheets("C").Move Before:=Sheets(7). so how can i make this so that "if sheet c exists, then move it". thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This short macro will do this

Yes for Ascending

No For Descending

```
Sub Sort_Active_Book()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim iAnswer As VbMsgBoxResult
'
' Prompt the user as which direction they wish to
' sort the worksheets.
'
   iAnswer = MsgBox("Sort Sheets in Ascending Order?" & Chr(10) _
     & "Clicking No will sort in Descending Order", _
     vbYesNoCancel + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton1, "Sort Worksheets")
   For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
      For j = 1 To Sheets.Count - 1
'
' If the answer is Yes, then sort in ascending order.
'
         If iAnswer = vbYes Then
            If UCase$(Sheets(j).Name) > UCase$(Sheets(j + 1).Name) Then
               Sheets(j).Move After:=Sheets(j + 1)
            End If
'
' If the answer is No, then sort in descending order.
'
         ElseIf iAnswer = vbNo Then
            If UCase$(Sheets(j).Name) < UCase$(Sheets(j + 1).Name) Then
               Sheets(j).Move After:=Sheets(j + 1)
            End If
         End If
      Next j
   Next i
End Sub
```

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/812386

Comment: thanks wessel, i can work with that code. exactly what i was looking for. and thanks for the link to microsoft, didn't think to check their site for a fix.